# Is there a specific way of creating a REPEAT_UNTIL loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, pseudocode

I've been given the pseudo-code:

```
REPEAT
    READ mark
UNTIL mark <= 100 and mark >= 0
```

It then continues on with various IF loops.

I need to reconstruct this code in Python, specifically **using a REPEAT-UNTIL loop**. I know how I can achieve this with a FOR or WHILE loop, but I haven't come across REPEAT-UNTIL in python before. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

***Edit: this is an exam question. Would I lose marks if I use Python and use a while loop  rather than using a different language that has REPEAT-UNTIL loops?***

Comment: There are no other looping constructs in Python other than `for` and `while`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a loop like what you describe but I often resort to things like:

```
while True:
     if condition:
         break
     do_stuff()  #this line may not ever be reached
```

or:

```
while True:
     do_stuff()      # this line gets executed at least once
     if condition:
         break
```